# JAva Vector Print

Tags: java, arrays, oop, vector, arraylist

I have a class Bank

```
public class Bank {
    public static final double INTEREST = 0.1;  //Interest rate charged on overdrawn accounts
    private Vector customers=new Vector();
    private Address address;

    public Bank() {
        //address = null;
    }

    public Bank(Address add) {
        customers = new Vector ();
        address = add;
    }

    // add a Customer to the customers Vector
    public void addCustomer(Customer cus) {
        customers.add(cus);
    }

    // get and set methods
    public Vector getCustomers() {
        return customers;
    }

    public void setCustomers(Vector v) {
        customers = v;
    }

}
```

now i am adding customers to the Banks class

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    int custnum=b.getBank().getCustomers().size()+1;
    ad=new Address(txtCustStreet.getText(),txtCustCity.getText(),txtCustPostCode.getText());
    cus=new Customer(txtCustName.getText(),ad,custnum, Integer.parseInt(txtoverdraft.getText()));

    if (e.getSource() == jbExit) {
        frame.dispose();
    }
    if (e.getSource() == jbSubmit) {
        // b.getBank().setCustomers(null);
        b.getBank().addCustomer(cus);
    }
    System.out.println(b.getBank().getCustomers().size());
}
```

when i am printing the vector size after adding 1 customers it prints 1
when i add two customers it prints like
1
2
while i add 3 customers it prints like 
1
2
3

i want only only to print 3 when i add 3 customers not 
1
2
3
please help me out thanks

Comment: What if there are 3 or more customers, still want to print something? Or do you only want to print when you have 3 customers?

Comment: There appears to be no loop in the actionPerformed method, which suggests that it is been called (probably) by a button. This will always only add a single new customer. Given how the information is obtained from the user, I don't particularly see away around it

Comment: like if i am adding 3 customers then size must be 3 only not print like 1,2,3, if size is four then i need 4 as a output but it prints like 1,2,3,4

Comment: Do I understand you correctly that you press the button three times, but want the size of the vector only be printed the third/last time? Given that this a some GUI application, will the console output be relevant at all?

Comment: it is like i am adding a customer then pressing the submit button my output is 1 .Now again i am adding the customer now my vector size is 2 so i want just 2 to be printed but it is prtinting like 1,2

Answer (score 2):

As MadProgrammer mentioned above it looks like you're using an `actionPerformed` method to add `Customers`.  This would cause you to see:

```
1
2
3
```

when you add 3 `Customers` because if you're doing this in an event handler then you must be triggering the event 3 times.  Each of these `ActionEvents` being handled is triggering the `actionPerformed` method which has a `System.out.println()` call at the end of it.  What's happening is that you're seeing all three numbers since each call is printing out the result of `b.getBank().getCustomers().size()` which is going up by one each time the method is called.

If you are triggering this with a button, try looking at your output between button clicks and you see that you'll have one line of output for each time you've clicked the button.  If that's the case and you want to only see the final size of your `Vector` then you'll have to move your `System.out.println()` call outside of your event handling method.